# How can I prevent Wicket AutocompleteAjaxComponent from escaping &nbsp;?

Tags: java, wicket

I'm trying to make an autocomplete field, using Wicket's `AutocompleteAjaxComponent`.

I want to put some space using `&nbsp` in the dropdown list values.

However, it's being escaped, and printed as literal text. I've tried to do `setEscapeModelStrings(false)` but to no avail.

What is the preferred way to not-escape these characters in `AutocompleteAjaxComponent`?

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is to use the unicode-escape `\u00A0` instead of `&nbsp;`, as that won't be escaped by AbstractAutoCompleteTextRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.autocomplete.AbstractAutoCompleteTextRenderer#renderChoice(T, Response, String)`:

https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/96bda7f1fd32ec5c8d1a8dfa5512fa643e2479a7/wicket-extensions/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/autocomplete/AbstractAutoCompleteTextRenderer.java#L35

See `org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.autocomplete.StringAutoCompleteRenderer` for inspiration. Pass your class' instance to `org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.autocomplete.AutoCompleteTextField#AutoCompleteTextField(String, IModel<T>, Class<T>, IAutoCompleteRenderer<T>, AutoCompleteSettings)`.